# How to define a class for child tags?

Tags: html, css, class

Assume there is a bunch of tags:

```
<parenttag>
    <!-- a bunch of tags -->
</parenttag>
```

I want the child tags to belong to the same class. How can I refer them to this class without specifying the class for the each of them, like just specify it once in the parent tag? Is it possible?

Comment: The outertag is called parent, the innertag called child. And no, you can not declare a class for childs within the parent. however you can adress child tags within css: `.parentClass p { }` as example.

Comment: @tacoshy I didn't get how exactly to address them the way you proposed

Comment: for example you have <div class="parent"><p>child paragraph</p></div> and you want to style that paragraph to have it written in red, you can adress in CSS with `.parent p { color: red; }`   -    you can of course use every other tag aswell, its not limited to pargraphs.

Comment: in the `style.css` file, you can *target* a child of a parent suing the example that @tacoshy gave. 

```
.parent .child {
    color : red; 
}
```

Comment: @tacoshy Ok I'll try this out, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `parenttag > *`,

sample:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .parent > * { color: red; }
</style>
<div class="parent">
  I am parent
  <p>I am child 1</p>
  <div>I am child 2 
    <span>I am child 2-1<span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great copy/paste

Answer (score 1):

You should use general selector `*` so `parenttag *` this will select all tags into parent tag, direct child and there children, etc. If you just want to target direct child of paretn you can use child selector `>` to make it like: `parenttag > *`

Comment: Is it that `parenttag *` includes the parent itself whereas `parenttag > *` does not?

Comment: No to include parent in both case you will need to make your css like `parenttags, parenttags *`

Comment: @Kaiyaha why not validate my answer ? As I am saying same as validate answer but 1h earlier?

Comment: Because an example was given + your english is kinda bad, it was quite hard to get what wou meant at first